# iframe load function kicks off on .append

Tags: jquery, iframe, load, append

Say I have this code:

```
var jqiFrame = $('<iframe name="jqiframe" id="jqiframe" src="about:blank"></iframe>');
$('body').append(jqiFrame);
jqiFrame.load(function() {
    // Some code
});
```

How can I make it so that the .load function only kicks off when the iFrame is actually loaded, vs. when it is appended to the body empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could not set the src attribute initially but do it later.

```
var jqiFrame = $('<iframe name="jqiframe" id="jqiframe"></iframe>');
$('body').append(jqiFrame);
jqiFrame.load(function() {
    // Some code
});
```

You could also just move your load before the append.

Answer (score 0):

You can also show it when its ready (else hidden):

CSS:

```
iframe{
    display:none;
}​
```

script:

```
var jqiFrame = $('<iframe name="jqiframe" id="jqiframe" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com"></iframe>');
$('body').append(jqiFrame);

jqiFrame.load(function() {
    alert("loaded");
    $("iframe").css("display","block");
});​
```